# RxJS: Queue the first source until the second source meet the predicate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, react-redux, redux-observable

How to achieve this scenario with RxJS.

When I want to fetch a user (1st source) then I need to check the internet connection (2nd source). If the internet is not connected, queue the first source until the internet is back on. If the internet is back on, emit the 1st source. I can make the later one but I can't get my head around how to queue the 1st source until the 2nd source is true.

Please check my code here:

```
const userEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(USER_REQUEST)
    .withLatestFrom(action$.ofType(CONNECTION))
    .filter(([first, second]) => second.value === true)
    .do(a => console.log('can fetch a user'))    
    .mapTo({ type: SUCCESS });
```

http://jsbin.com/zomikukiqi/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Hey there. Can you clarify this further? The example code doesn't seem to match up with the description (no user, no internet check, behavior doesn't seem related, etc) It's very likely queuing observables isn't the ideal solution so also try to explain without that assumption, if possible :)

Comment: Hi Sorry, I amended the sample code to reflect the description. I also improve the jsbin code. In jsbin when you click, disconnect then start request, then click connect, I should see the `can fetch a user` in the console. It should be fine to dispatch the last value of the 1st source or even better dispatch all values that hasn't been emitted. I looked at `buffer` operator but don't know how to buffer the 1st source. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `buffer()` to store USER_REQUEST until CONNECTION triggers buffer flush.

```js
const USER_REQUEST = 'USER_REQUEST';
const CONNECTION = 'CONNECTION';
const SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';

const requestUser = () => ({ type: USER_REQUEST });
const connection = (x) => ({ type: CONNECTION, value: x });

const bufferedUserRequests$ = (action$, store) =>
  action$.ofType(USER_REQUEST)
    .filter(x => !store.getState().connectionStatus)    
    .buffer(action$.ofType(CONNECTION))

const unbufferedUserRequests$ = (action$, store) =>
  action$.ofType(USER_REQUEST)
    .filter(x => store.getState().connectionStatus)    
    .map(request => [request])

const userEpic = (action$, store) =>
   Rx.Observable.merge(
     bufferedUserRequests$(action$, store), 
     unbufferedUserRequests$(action$, store)
   )
   .flatMap(bufferArray => 
     bufferArray.map(request => Rx.Observable.of(request))
   )
   .do(a => console.log('can fetch a user'))
   .mapTo({ type: SUCCESS })

const reducer = (state = { connectionStatus: false}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CONNECTION:
      return { ...state, connectionStatus: action.value }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// components/App.js

const { connect } = ReactRedux;

let App = ({ requestUser, connection, connectionStatus }) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={requestUser}>Start Request</button>
    <p>Internet Connection: {connectionStatus.toString()}</p>
    <button onClick={() => connection(false)}>Disconnect</button>
    <button onClick={() => connection(true)}>Connect</button>
  </div>
);

App = connect(
  ({ connectionStatus }) => ({ connectionStatus }),
  { requestUser, connection }
)(App);

// redux/configureStore.js

const { Provider } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware } = Redux;
const { createEpicMiddleware } = ReduxObservable;

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(userEpic);

const store = createStore(reducer,
  applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware)
);

// index.js

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.2.1/dist/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.2.1/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@^3.5.2/dist/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@4.4.5/dist/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux-observable/dist/redux-observable.min.js"></script>
  <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @richard-matsen. That is what I am looking for. `mergeAll` also can simplify this code:

`.flatMap(bufferArray => 
     bufferArray.map(request => Rx.Observable.of(request))
   )`

Comment: Indeed it can, well spotted.